# Bash: how to avoid duplicate result from random list?

Tags: bash, random

Suppose a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
array[0]="123"
array[1]="333"
array[2]="5566"
array[3]="135"
array[4]="68"
array[5]="45"
array[6]="78"
array[7]="32"
array[8]="190"

number()
{
size=${#array[@]}
index=$(($RANDOM % $size))
sleep 0.5s
echo  Lucky number is ... ${array[$index]}
}

for i in {1..21}; do number; done
```

Is ok..I want to get random number in the interval,but show also a lot of dups

```
Lucky number is ... 135
Lucky number is ... 135
Lucky number is ... 5566
Lucky number is ... 78
Lucky number is ... 190
Lucky number is ... 333
Lucky number is ... 190
Lucky number is ... 135
Lucky number is ... 5566
Lucky number is ... 333
Lucky number is ... 45
Lucky number is ... 45
Lucky number is ... 68
Lucky number is ... 68
Lucky number is ... 333
Lucky number is ... 78
Lucky number is ... 78
Lucky number is ... 5566
Lucky number is ... 78
Lucky number is ... 333
Lucky number is ... 135
```

I want a result like this

```
Lucky number is ... 135
Lucky number is ... 5566
Lucky number is ... 78
Lucky number is ... 190
Lucky number is ... 333
Lucky number is ... 45
Lucky number is ... 68
```

So we can get the "Lucky number" without dups,unique
Someone know how to do?
Editing the script and reduced 21 to 9 don't change,I get even duplicates.

```
Lucky number is ... 135
Lucky number is ... 68
Lucky number is ... 45
Lucky number is ... 333
Lucky number is ... 78
Lucky number is ... 135
Lucky number is ... 135
Lucky number is ... 333
Lucky number is ... 32
```

Comment: you asked for 21 random numbers from a set of 9 numbers ... I'm not sure what you expected to happen there?

Comment: I have reduced 21 to 9 and is the same thing. Give me a 9 numbers but with some repeat for one or more times

Comment: do an `unset array[index]` after you’ve `echo`ed your Lucky number ? or piping your output to the `uniq` command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the list like a deck of cards. **Shuffle** the numbers, then read them out one at a time.

See [Simple method to shuffle the elements of an array in BASH shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42193673).

```
#!/bin/bash
array=("123" "333" "5566" "135" "68" "45" "78" "32" "190")

shuffle() {
    array=($(shuf -e "${array[@]}"))
    index=0
}

number() {
   size=${#array[@]}
   sleep 0.5s

   if (( index >= size )) ; then
      shuffle
   fi

   echo Lucky number is ... ${array[$index]}
   index=$((index + 1))
}

for i in {1..21}; do number; done
```